# How can I open multiple copies of phpMyAdmin simultaneously to our mySQL database server when it is busy?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, kill

This is my first nervous question on SO because all of my questions in the last decade have already had excellent answers.

I have searched all the terms that I can think of with no  hits that appear to address the problem - either on SO or Google generally...

For the last 15 years we have used phpMyAdmin to administer a linux MySQL manufacturing database of about 100 tables, some of which are now 50 to 300 million records each.  Ongoing development is constant, and manual lookup of various tables to correct erroneous data, or to modify table indexes etc are frequent as the size of the data grows.  All of this is internal to our fast network - i.e. accessed via our intranet.  Most queries are short, and the database runs responsively at a low average loading.

As may be understood, DBA mistakes happen.  For example to speed up a slow query, an additional index may be added to a large table without enough thought.  At this point, the re-indexing may take 30 minutes, and the manufacturing applications (written in php for Apache2 also on a linux server) come to an immediate halt.  This is not appreciated in the factory.

And here is the real problem.  I cannot then from my development PC open a second instance of phpMyAdmin to kill the unwanted MySQL process while it is still busy. Which is the very time I need to most :-)  The browser just goes into waiting for the phpMyAdmin page to load until after the long query is finished.

If I happen to have a second instance pf phpMyAdmin **open already**, I can look up the process and kill it satisfactorily.  Normallly, my only resort is to restart Apache2 and/or MySQL on the server.  This is too drastic and requires re-starting many client machines as well in order to re-establish necessary manufacturing connections to the database.

I have seen reference on SO that Apache will queue requests from the same IP address in the case of php programs using file-based session management, but it seems to me that I have no control over how phpMyAdmin uses its sessions.

I also read some time ago that if multiple CPU cores were brought into play on the database server, multiple simultaneous connections could be made despite one such query still being busy.  I cannot now find any reference to this concept.

**Does anyone please know** how to permit or force a second phpMyAdmin connection from the same PC to the same database server using phpMyAdmin while the first instance of phpMyAdmin is still tied up with a previous slow query?

Many thanks, Jem Stanners

Comment: phpMyAdmin Is just another PHP script, you should really learn how to interact with MySQL without it

Comment: why aren't you using a cli?

Comment: the problem is not with you phpMyAdmin but with mysql,if it stops all your instances

Comment: LOL. I am a casualty of m%soft - I don't touch type, and am addicted to GUIs. :-)

Comment: Did you try opening the second instance in another browser?

Comment: Thank you Marc Delisle.  That was the golden answer.  I now understand what the old question "How do I configure Apache2 to allow multiple simultaneous connections from same IP address?" from 7 years ago is about.  If you can't change the state of the sessions, avoid them altogether!  Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

- Try mySQL Workbench
  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
- Try upgrading servers RAMs an processors
- Consider cleaning the tables and delete rows if possible
- Consider shifting to Oracle (cost is to be considered)